# I have url, user name and password how do i get token from openAM?

Tags: openam

there is application that is deployed on openAM. for that particular application I have url, user Name and password how do i get token from that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your description is very vague, but OpenAM offers many ways to authenticate a user; Distribute Auth (GUI), GUI Login, OpenAM Auth API, REST API ...